# In JavaScript, what happens if I assign to an object property that has a getter but no setter?

Tags: javascript, object, properties, getter-setter

In the following code, both uses of `console.log(o.x)` print `1`. What happens to the assignment `o.x = 2`? Is it just ignored?

```
var o = {
    get x() {
        return 1;
    }
}

console.log(o.x);  // 1
o.x = 2
console.log(o.x);  // 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In sloppy mode, yes, it'll just be ignored - the value "assigned" will be discarded. But in strict mode (which is recommended), the following error will be thrown:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property x of `#<Object>` which has only a getter

```js
'use strict';
var o = {
    get x() {
        return 1;
    }
}

console.log(o.x);  // 1
o.x = 2
```