# In JavaScript's strict mode, why is reading a set-only property not an error?

Tags: javascript, object, properties, getter-setter, strict

I've [recently learned](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53579207/200783) that if I try to write to a JavaScript property that has `get` but no `set`, it is ignored in "sloppy mode", but is an error in strict mode.

OTOH, if I try to read from a `set`-only property, this returns `undefined` in both modes. Is there a reason why this is not also an error in strict mode?

Comment: Accessing a property that doesn't exist always gives `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably because it's common practice to test if an object `obj`'s property `prop` has a value by doing

```
if (obj.prop) { ...
```

or

```
if (obj.prop !== undefined) { ...
```

One of the objectives of **strict mode** (as stated on MDN) is:

> 1. Eliminates some JavaScript silent errors by changing them to throw errors.

When a programmer tries to set an unsettable property, the intention of the programmer is clear, i.e. they want to set a property. So the engine can warn you by throwing an error.

But when you do `obj.prop`, the intention isn't very clear. As doing `obj.kljasfbbsdbgjksb` (a key that is not defined) is also perfectly legal.

Is the programmer trying to *get* the value, or simply inspect the nature of `obj.prop` by doing `typeof obj.prop`, `obj.prop === undefined`, etc.